# Bitcore = "Error: More than one instance of bitcore-lib found"

Tags: website-integration, bitcore, dependencies

These two lines (and nothing more), create an error:

```
var exp = require('bitcore-explorers');
var btc = require('bitcore-lib');

Error: More than one instance of bitcore-lib found. Please make sure to require bitcore-lib and check that submodules do not also include their own bitcore-lib dependency.
```

I could see that this issue has been documented [here](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/issues/1366), as well as [here](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-payment-protocol/issues/30), and [here](https://forum.bitcore.io/t/more-than-one-instance-of-bitcore-lib-found/699). I read these pages, but I am still unable to overcome the issue.

Can someone please help? How do you do when trying to import different modules of `bitcore`?

Comment: Any news on this problem? According to other threads it seems rather intractable. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: I have not found a solution to that unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that's the right method but it does work.

```
delete global._bitcore
var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib')
```

Comment: Is it the right way to do..? and it'll not stop bitcore-lib right..?

Answer (score 1):

See
Add this line prior bitcore definition:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, '_bitcore', { get(){ return undefined }, set(){} })
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/issues/1457#issuecomment-467594031).