# Unable to get balance with bitcore lib

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, balance, bitcore

Using latest version of bitcore lib , want to check balance for making tx but once I include

```
var explorers =require('bitcore-explorers');
```

after

```
var bitcore =require('bitcore-lib');

Error: More than one instance of bitcore-lib found. Please make sure to require bitcore-lib and check that submodules do not also include their own bitcore-lib dependency.
at Object.bitcore.versionGuard (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/bitcore-lib/index.js:12:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/bitcore-lib/index.js:15:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/controllers/bitcoinController.js:8:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/routes/apiRoutes.js:5:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/api/server.js:13:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

I had a look at this thread

[Bitcore = "Error: More than one instance of bitcore-lib found"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46795/bitcore-error-more-than-one-instance-of-bitcore-lib-found)

but it does not help . 
When I comment out this part

```
var bitcore =require('bitcore-lib');
```

explorer seem to be running but the problem is it always returns 0 for all the wallets . 
For instance this wallet  has fonds [wallet testnet fonds](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/address/mgZsaffMAow9TR21BQHY9HfTdbPdJFkww2/)

here is the code

```
const insight = new explorers.Insight();
insight.getUnspentUtxos('mkFPBvd3jbPYn4223SNTneBWHodziU287G', function(err, utxos) {
    console.log(utxos);
    let balance = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < utxos.length; i++) {
        balance +=utxos[i]['satoshis'];
    }
    console.log('balance:'+ balance);
});
```

and response is always  [] , 0

1) How to check balance using bitcore without conflict with bitcore-lib  ?

2) Which is the  "web3" (most commonly  used for ethereum) node js library for bitcoin ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is the only thing I've found about solving this issue so far. Seems like a total hack / oversight.

https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/issues/1454#issuecomment-306900782